# How to get scan codes of arrow keys?

Tags: c, turbo-c

I'm implementing a small puzzle game in C in which I need to get the scan codes of 4 arrow
keys. Actually,in C programming I implement the
puzzle game in which we are required to get scan codes of arrow keys
and I have to use `getkey()` function which is a user defined
function. But I don't know what is the format of this `getkey()` function.

Please tell me a easy way to get scan codes of arrow keys and explain in details. I'm using turbo C and I know it is old but still I want it.

Comment: In standard C there is no way of getting scan-codes of *any* keys. You might want to use more platform/OS specific functions to read the arrow keys.

Comment: On Windows: Up-Arrow - 38, Down-Arrow - 40.

Comment: You could just write a program to print which keys were pressed and use that to determine the values you are interested in.

Comment: I added some tags, which I believe match the question. Please remove if I got it wrong!

Comment: You're using a 22 year old compiler? ...What?

Comment: @PatrickCollins It seems to be popular in some schools, I gather, because quite a lot of Turbo C (and worse, Turbo C++) questions are asked here... And I actually think it is fine (for a very low value of "fine"), as long as the students are clearly told they're learning programming, not really modern C (and especially not modern C++).

Comment: i got my answer....thank u everyone for helping me......just one question i want to ask.How to make use of alphabets W,A,S,D for UP,LEFT,DOWN,RIGHT to make effect.

Comment: @YogiGaikwad Just use them? Anyway, if you have a new question, ask a new question, preferably with relevant code in the question text. Also, assuming the one answer here helped, you could accept it (by clicking the big check mark at the corner of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        c = _getch();
        printf("%d\n",c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note (since I just removed the conio tag which I added earlier, as I think it does not apply): this code uses `conio.h`, but should most likely give the same scan codes the `getkey` function mentioned in the question does.

Comment: @hyde: So call your `getkey` function instead then.

Comment: Yep, and I think your code is much better as a generally useful SO answer this way.